# How to combine two different tables with different columns

Tags: sql

I have a situation where I need to combine two different tables with different columns.

[image: As shown in this screenshot]

**DDL**:

```
create table tableA ([timestamp] datetime, [source] char(1), [description] varchar(20));
insert into tableA values
('2018-10-12', 'a', 'first day'),
('2018-10-13', 'b', 'alarms'),
('2018-10-14', 'c', 'processing');

create table tableB ([timestamp] datetime, entity varchar(20));
insert into tableB values
('2018-10-12', 'new env'),
('2018-10-13', 'resource'),
('2018-10-18', 'integrated');
```

I have different columns in two different tables. And I need to combine it as shown in screenshot using SQL.

Comment: Don't call a date column TimeStamp... A timestamp also includes hours, minutes and seconds.

Comment: jarlh I know it contains time. This is just a demo.

Comment: Joining on timestamps isn't very safe.

Comment: But I have no other way around to get results as required.

Comment: Is there any way to have an additional column of tablename in the resultant table of this join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `full join`. Try this query:

```
select coalesce (a.timestamp, b.timestamp), source, description, entity
from tableA a
full join tableB b on a.timestamp = b.timestamp
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7f7d7/2)

Comment: Great you save my day. Thanks @Michal Turczyn

Answer (score 2):

Use union all

```
select a.timestamp, a.source,a.description,b.entity
from tableA a left join tableB b on a.timestamp=b.timestamp 
where b.timestamp is not null
union all
select b.timestamp, a.source,a.description,b.entity
from tableA a right join tableB b on a.timestamp=b.timestamp 
where a.timestamp is null
```

Comment: Or use FULL OUTER JOIN if your SQL allows that

Comment: @Volodymyr, yes some db does not allow full outer join that's why i write the alternative

Answer (score 1):

You can use `INNER JOIN` for this

```
SELECT a.TimeStamp, a.Source, a.Description, b.Entity 
FROM TableA a
LEFT JOIN Tableb b ON a.TimeStamp=b.TimeStamp; 
UNION
SELECT a.TimeStamp, a.Source, a.Description, b.Entity 
FROM TableA a
RIGHT JOIN Tableb b ON a.TimeStamp=b.TimeStamp;
```

Comment: This will not work with the last row 18.10.2018 because it is not in TABLE A

Comment: @silva, have you run this query - it will not the desired result for OP

Comment: Oh yea didnt see that last different dates, will edit this and use union as query

Answer (score 0):

Use Below code

```
SELECT isnull(t1.TimeStamp, t2.TimeStamp) TimeStamp, t1.source,t1.description, t2.entity from table1 t1 FULL OUTER JOIN table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id
```